# Converting XML string to scala XML literal

Tags: xml, scala, multilinestring

I'm trying to convert the given XML string to Scala XML literal.

```
e.g.
import scala.xml.XML.loadString

> val xml = """<parent>
             |<child id="1">data1</child>
             |<child id="2">data2</child>
             |<child id="3">data3</child>
             |</parent>""".stripMargin

> loadString(xml)

> res0: scala.xml.Elem =
        <parent> //0
        <child id="1">data1</child> //1
        <child id="2">data2</child> //2
        <child id="3">data3</child> //3        // Expected Output
        </parent>
```

The problem is, when I have an attribute of XML element in a *seperate* line, it throws Error,

```
> val xml = """<parent>
             |<child id="1">data1</child>
             |<child id="2">data2</child>
             |<child
             |id="3">data3</child>
             |</parent>""".stripMargin


> loadString(xml)

> res1: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element type "child" must be followed by 
      either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

I tried to remove `(\n or \r)` chars in the XML string, it doesn't work,
Is there any method to handle this in Scala?

Comment: What versions are you using? Have you tried putting in a file rather than REPL? This seems to work OK in a file in Scala 2.12.8 and scala-xml 1.1.1.

Comment: hi @Tim, I'm using Scala version  2.13.1. you're right, it is working fine, when I put the string in a file, I was just curious, if there is any method to handle it directly.

Comment: I was suggesting that you put the code in a file, not the string. I have cut and paste this code into a file and compiled it, and it works OK, so this may be a REPL issue of some kind.

Comment: thanks for the help @Tim